# Why minor GC duration changes so much when an element of a large array is updated?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have the following simple program:

```java
public class GCArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] bigArr = new Object[1 << 24];
        Object[] smallArr = new Object[1 << 12]; 

        bigArr[0x897] = new Object();
        smallArr[0x897] = new Object();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
            smallArr[0x897] = new Object();  // (*)
            //bigArr[0x897] = new Object();
        }

        // to prevent bigArr and smallArr from being garbage collected
        bigArr[0x897] = new Object();
        smallArr[0x897] = new Object();
    }
}
```

When I run it using ParallelGC as GC algorithm for young generation:

```sh
java -classpath . -XX:InitialHeapSize=4G -XX:MaxHeapSize=4G -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC GCArrays
```

the average pause times I get are below 1ms:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1047584K->32K(1048064K)] 1113476K->65924K(4193792K), 0.0007385 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

However if I change the line marked with `(*)` to modify `bigArr` instead of `smallArr` the pause time increases to 10ms:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1047584K->32K(1048064K)] 1113468K->65916K(4193792K), 0.0101251 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Note that the program only modifies a single element of the array. However it looks like JVM still scans the whole array to find live objects during minor collection.  Is my guess explaining longer GC pauses correct? Why the whole array needs to be scanned when only one element is modified in this case?

Comment: How does it know that only one element has changed (without scanning the whole array)?

Comment: @Holger GC only need to scan "drity" part of array. There is a dirty card associated with every 512 bytes of heap

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin such an optimization doesn’t change the fact that a garbage collector doesn’t know that only a single reference has changed before scanning a memory region. And obviously, the garbage collector used in the OP’s setup doesn’t do such an optimization.

Comment: @Hogler, does it mean that when PSYoungGen looks for root set references corresponding to the marked card it finds both the modified element reference and the reference to the array itself, while ParNew only finds the modified element reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html) explains concept of dirty cards and their role in young GC.

In both cases singe memory address in old space is "dirtied" and thus single card. For reference array object spanning multiple cards (512 byte blocks) only card for really modified index subrange is modified.

As only single card is "dirtified", GC only need to scan corresponding 512 bytes of memory.

With `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` both "smallArr" and "bigArr" versions are showing similar timings.

`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` + `smallArr`

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [ParNew: 419458K->2K(471872K), 0.0015320 secs] 485365K->65909K(996160K), 0.0015635 secs] 
[Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` + `bigArr`

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [ParNew: 419458K->2K(471872K), 0.0020550 secs] 485365K->65909K(996160K), 0.0020885 secs] 
[Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

Though this `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC`, it seems that GC has to scan whole "bigArr"

`-XX:+ParallelOldGC` + `smallArr`

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 522768K->16K(523520K)] 588691K->65939K(1047808K), 0.0009430 secs] 
[Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

`-XX:+ParallelOldGC` + `bigArr`

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 522768K->16K(523008K)] 588687K->65935K(1047296K), 0.0149276 secs] 
[Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

`-XX:+ParallelOldGC` + `bigArr = new Object[1 << 25]`

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 522768K->16K(523520K)] 654219K->131467K(1047808K), 0.0413473 secs]
[Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
```

Counter intuitively `ParallelOldGC` and `ConcMarkSweepGC` are using different implementations of very similar young GC algorithm.

It looks like `PSYoungGen` is missing optimization to scan only dirty portion of object array.

Comment: Indeed it looks like it is case of missing optimization.